# python pandas rename data frame

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

The purpose of this code is to scrape a bunch of data tables with different lengths (different number of rows per table), turn them into pandas data frames, remove some unnecessary columns and fix the date.

All the above works ok but when I tried to rename a column I got an error.

Here is data sample:

Date  Actual

0    Oct 15, 2018 21:30

1    Sep 09, 2018 21:30    0.7%

2    Aug 08, 2018 21:30    0.3%

3    Jul 09, 2018 21:30   -0.1%

4    Jun 08, 2018 21:30   -0.2%

5    May 09, 2018 21:30   -0.2%

6    Apr 10, 2018 21:30   -1.1%

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd


class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\sample.txt").readlines()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def title(self):
        names = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/h1').text
            if title not in names:
                names.append(title)
        return names

    def table(self):
        DataFrames = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            while True:
                try:
                    item = self.wait.until(
                        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"showMoreHistory")]/a')))
                    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
                except Exception:
                    break

            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
            pos = 0
            for table in self.wait.until(
                    ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
                data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td]")]
                if data:
                    df.loc[pos] = data[0:5]
                    pos += 1

            df["Date"] = df["Release Date"].apply(lambda date: date[:12]) + " " + df["Time"]
            df.astype('unicode')
            df = df[['Date', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous', 'Release Date', 'Time']]
            pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %d, %Y %H:%M')

            df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
            df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
            df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
            df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
            df = df.reset_index()
            if df not in DataFrames:
                DataFrames.append(df)
        return DataFrames

    def rename(self):
        tabels = self.table()
        names = self.title()
        for tabel, name in zip(tabels, names):
            tabel.rename({'Actual': name})



x = DataEngine()
x.rename()
```

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 67, in 
    x.rename()

File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 59, in rename
    tabels = self.table()

File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 54, in table
    if df not in DataFrames:

File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1613, in f

```
raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: can you give us a sample of the dataframes you're using?

Comment: `df.rename(columns={'previous':'new'},inplace=True)`

Comment: @– mad_ not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your multiple calls to `df.drop` are unnecessary, and makes reading the code more visually tiring. Change:

```
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()
```

To:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[-4:], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I've added the `drop=True` because I doubt you need it anymore.

Second, to actually answer your question, your problem is actually occurring on the line where you call `if df not in DataFrames`. On this line, Python is effectively returning:

```
not any(all(df == df_i) for df_i in DataFrames)
```

when it evaluates `df not in DataFrames`.

This comparison will fail (specifically at `df == df_i`) if either `DataFrame` doesn't have the same columns *or same index*.

Try putting in something like the following:

```
try:
    if df not in DataFrames:
        DataFrames.append(df)
except ValueError:
    for df_i in DataFrames:
        print(df.columns)
        print(df.columns == df_i.columns)
        print(df.index == df_i.index)
```

Likely you'll find discrepancies.

Comment: you are right a lot of error popup when i tried your edit